# table data does not display message No data availabe

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

why when I filter data where there is no data table it does not display the message No data available in table, I use three table relations through the model and server side in this ajax my code:
Controller with function json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRzBv.jpg)

ajax in blade
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0DdN.jpg)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Do not post code as images. Please use the code tags.

Comment: Please [do not post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead, [edit] the question and post the actual text - [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for readability.

Comment: If you have not yet done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].